# Extract VPC endpoint IP addresses in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am creating a CloudFormation template to create the necessary infrastructure to host static websites using S3 bucket. The template includes creating a VPC endpoint of type Interface and then creating a Load Balancer. When creating the Target Group for the Load Balancer, I need to enter the IP addresses from the subnets from the VPC endpoint into the [Targets property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup.html#cfn-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup-targets). The only attribute that can be retrieved after creating a VPC endpoint is `NetworkInterfaceIds`, but that does not return IP addresses. I found [this article](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/transfer-for-sftp-restrict-ip-cloudformation/) that uses a Lambda function to extract IP addresses from the `NetworkInterfaceIds` attribute passed in, but I don't want to create a Lambda function just to get IP addresses from a VPC endpoint when creating the infrastructure.

My question is, is it possible to extract the created IP addresses of a VPC endpoint without creating a Lambda function, or is it at least possible to delete this function after creating the whole infrastructure? The Lambda function would logically be unused and therefore I would not like to have it created unnecessarily.

Thanks in advance for your help

**CloudFormation template code example:**

```
StaticWebSitesVpcEndpoint:
  Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
  Properties:
    VpcEndpointType: Interface
    ServiceName: com.amazonaws.eu-central-1.s3
    VpcId: !Ref VPC
    SubnetIds:
      - xyz # SUBNET 1 ID
      - xyz # SUBNET 2 ID
    SecurityGroupIds:
      - xyz

StaticWebSitesTargetGroup:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  Properties:
    TargetType: ip
    Targets:
      - Id: IP1 # HERE I NEED SUBNET 1 IP
      - Id: IP2 # HERE I NEED SUBNET 2 IP
    Protocol: HTTP
    Port: 80
    ProtocolVersion: HTTP1
    Matcher:
      - HttpCode: 200,307,405
    VpcId: !Ref VPC
```